# Why my Kendo grid shows checkbox disabled?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, telerik

This is my kendo grid:

```
.Columns(columns =>
        {

        columns.Bound(c => c.Revisado).ClientTemplate("<input disabled='' type='checkbox' #= Revisado ? checked='checked':'' # class='chkbx' />")/*Template(t => @Html.CheckBox("chkSelect")).Width("5%").*/.HeaderTemplate(h => @Html.CheckBox("chkSelect", new { id = "chkTodos", title = "Seleccionar todo", onclick = "javascript:selectTodos($('#grddocs'));" }));
            columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Hidden(true);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Fecha).Title("Indexado el");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Usuario.ClaveUsuario).Title("Indexado por");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Cliente.NIFCIF).Title("Interviniente");
            columns.Bound(c => c.TipoDocumental).Title("Tipo documental");
            columns.Bound(c => c.NombreDocumento).Title("Nombre documento");
            columns.Bound(c => c.NombreDocumentoSGDAE).Title("Nombre documento Fired-Renting");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Revisado).Hidden(true);
            })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(10)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(i => i.ID);
            }
            ))
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

You can see the checkbox is disabled.

How can enabled them?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `disabled=''` from your client template in checkbox column:

```
.ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= Revisado ? checked='checked':'' # class='chkbx' />")
```

Comment: @anmarti the caveat is that if you enable it you might have problems because you change the value but the value is not updated in the model. This is why in the templates of checkboxes they use to be disabled.